# How do you print the address of an object in C++?

Tags: c++

If I have the following basic C++ program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class CRectangle {
    int x, y;
  public:
    void set_values (int,int);
    int area () {return (x*y);}
};

void CRectangle::set_values (int a, int b) {
  x = a;
  y = b;
}

int main () {
  CRectangle rect;
  rect.set_values (3,4);
  cout << "area: " << rect.area() <<endl;
  cout <<&rect<<endl;
  cin.get();
  return 0;
}
```

is the last print statement printing the address of the variable rect or the address of the object? are they the same? or are they the same?

Comment: Your question makes no sense. There is only one object, and its name is `rect`. Of course they are the same.

Comment: If I knew they were the same, why would I have asked the question?

Comment: Don't use `cin.get();` to keep a dead program alive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are the same.  It's printing the address of rect which is the same as the address of the object.  Rect is on the stack, and thus the entire object is as well.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as an address of a Class if thats what you mean?  &CRectangle does not exist , only an address of an instance of the class (&rect) exists.  No memory is occupied by the Class definition itself.

Comment: The first claim is true, but if the class has virtual members, the class definition will require a vtable stored in static memory. The same happens if there are static members in the class.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `rect` is an object of `CRectablge`, so there is no difference between the address of the variable and the object in this case.

Answer (score 0):

`rect` is just an identifier for an object in the stack. In this case, an instance of `CRectangle`.

By calling `&rect`, you'll be getting the address, in the stack, where the object resides.